# How To Get External/Guest Office 365 User Photo?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

We are successfully using Graph Api with SharePoint Framework (SPFX) to get current user photo. BUT this only works for users within the organization.
For guest users this is not working. I have tried using AAD Graph API but it seems that also requires users within the organization.
The external/guest users have assigned O365 licenses.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to get the Guest User's Photo.

Based on my test, we can get it if the user had modified his photo and login in outlook. I have get a user with the mail address `onmicrosoft.com`

The simple code like this:

`await _serviceClient.Me.Photo.Request().GetAsync();`

We can also see that some users are not support this action. For more detail, we can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/photo-rest-operations).

Comment: If the user is external with an email outside of the Microsoft online services  this is not working. I get message "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox". Because there is not mailbox.